# How do I get the tag name and CSS classes from Nokogiri::HTML

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I've been trying to parse these [HTML files](http://uscodebeta.house.gov/download/download.shtml;jsessionid=19D1AD1CDC51A994396F2FC9D8E25228) with Nokogiri. This is the code I was using

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML File.open('usc...html', 'r')
children = doc.css('body div')
children.each do |child|
    puts child.name
end
```

That prints `div` for all of the child elements even though they are almost entire `p`, `h3` and `h4` tags. Can someone explain why that is happening? Also, how do I get the CSS classes off of them?

Comment: there are several xml files.. can you put the one here,which you are using?

Comment: Please show us a snippet of the XML you are trying to parse. Don't make us wade through a number of files on a remote site. Otherwise, *WHEN* that link breaks due to link-rot, the question will be meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
doc.css('body div')
```

Will select every div on the page. If you want every element you should use:

```
doc.css('*')
```

You can get at the css class with `child[:class]`